# I can not create more than 5 tasks in freeRTOS

Tags: freertos

When i create more than 5 tasks in freeRTOS the scheduler does not start. I am using the board KL46Z Freedom from Freescale. I know that the scheduler does not start because when i debug the program gets stuck in the **FOR** which is after the line that starts the scheduler (**PEX_RTOS_START()**)

```
 #ifdef PEX_RTOS_START
    PEX_RTOS_START();                  /* Startup of the selected RTOS. Macro is defined by the RTOS component. */
  #endif
  /*** End of RTOS startup code.  ***/
  /*** Processor Expert end of main routine. DON'T MODIFY THIS CODE!!! ***/
  for(;;){} // I GET STUCK HERE!
  /*** Processor Expert end of main routine. DON'T WRITE CODE BELOW!!! ***/
} /*** End of main routine. DO NOT MODIFY THIS TEXT!!! ***/
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to increase the HEAP size in **FreeRTOSConfig.h**. The default HEAP size for the KL46z is 8192:

```
 #define configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE      8192 /* Size of heap in bytes */
```

I increased this value to 16384, and it worked!

```
#define configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE             16384/* Size of heap in bytes */
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an official FreeRTOS demo (from the FreeRTOS download) then read the comment by the loop you say you get stuck by and it will tell you exactly why you get stuck there, and give you advice on resources to help you fix it.  You can also check the documentation for the [xTaskCreate()](http://www.freertos.org/a00125.html) API function, or alternatively to know if you have enough RAM at compile time (rather than run time) you could create a completely statically allocated system by setting configSUPPORT_STATIC_ALLOCATION to 1, configSUPPORT_DYNAMIC_ALLOCATION to 0, and using [xTaskCreateStatic()](http://www.freertos.org/xTaskCreateStatic.html) instead of xTaskCreate().